# Dart js-interop and overloaded methods

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

How do you handle interfacing with JS libraries that have overloaded methods?
For example Leaflet.js has both of the following defined for the Map object:

```
openPopup(popup); // opens the given popup
openPopup(html, LatLng, popOptions); // creates a popup with the html at the location, using the popup options.
```

What I've come up with is:

```
@JS("L.Map")
class Map {
   /* code */
   external Map openPopup(dynamic popup, [LatLng coords, PopupOptions opts]);
   /* code */
}
```

Is there a better way? Note: this seems to work but the analyzer complains: The method openPopup is not defined for the class Map.

Dart: 1.17.1
package:js-0.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I have not been able to specify a different name for an instance member/method using the `JS()` directive which is a big issue especially for javascript object that have method names that clash with Dart keywords (such as 'catch' in a javascript Promise). I ended up using plain `dart:js`. And anyway even when using `package/js`, I ended up adding another layer to make the api more dartish (especially with callbacks and promise) especially to enforce argument types.

What I would expect would be to be able to do (in your example)

```
@JS("L.Map")
class Map {
   JS('openPopup')
   external Map openPopupHtml(String html, [LatLng coords, PopupOptions opts]);
   JS('openPopup')
   external Map openPopup(Popup popup);
}
```

but that does not seem to work. Maybe should it be considered as a feature enhancement.

Comment: See http://dartbug.com/24779 . Initially closed as _WontFix_ but reconsidered recently for Dart2 \o/

Comment: @alextk - That was my expectation as well.